# Time difference between datetime and timedelta for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to find the seconds difference between a datetime variable and a timedelta variable.

So my endtime variable is in timedelta format but the relevant information is 09:59:06.374829103

My starttime variable is in datetime format and the relevant information is 9:58

I want to find the difference between these two

```
df['endTime'][0]:
output: Timedelta('0 days 09:59:06.374829103')

df['startTime'][0]
output: datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 6, 9, 58)
```

I want how many seconds for:

```
(df['endTime'][0] - df['startTime'][0]) seconds
```

Comment: What do you mean to find the seconds difference between point in time and a time span?

Comment: What is supposedly the correct answer here? A `datetime` is a fixed point in time. A `timedelta` is a *duration*, independent of any point in time. There's no correct answer here, unless you can define how one might arrive at an answer.

Comment: @deceze. I think the OP wants the difference between 9:59:06 and 9:58:00.

Comment: Yes exactly! @Corralien. TH

Comment: That means that this is XY problem. The real question is how to get end time as datetime object, not timedelta. How do you get it as time delta in the first place - fix that. So still missing details and clarity

Comment: So the `timedelta` is supposed to be relative to the start time's date at midnight…? Then take the start time's date portion, combine it with `time(0, 0, 0)`, and add the `timedelta` to it. Then you have two `datetime`s you can get the difference of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dt` accessor to convert `DatetimeIndex` in `total_seconds`:

```
# dt - dt.normalize() remove the date part and keep only time
>>> df['endTime'].dt.total_seconds() - \
        df['startTime'].sub(df['startTime'].dt.normalize()).dt.total_seconds()

0    66.374829
dtype: float64
```

Input data:

```
>>> df
                    endTime           startTime
0 0 days 09:59:06.374829103 2023-01-06 09:58:00

>>> df.dtypes
endTime      timedelta64[ns]
startTime     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I get the following:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: Try to convert your columns: `df['endTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['endTime'])` and `df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'])`

Comment: For your first row, does it work: `df['endTime'][0].total_seconds() - (df['startTime'][0] - df['startTime'][0].normalize()).total_seconds()`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'datetime' object has no attribute 'normalize'

Comment: Did you try to convert the two columns?

Comment: So one of my columns is a string of a epoch so I tried running this for one example:
 datetime.fromtimestamp(1673017140.0)

Comment: So ideally I would convert the string timestamps to datetime in the column and then perform your solution but I do not know how to do that either. Would really appreciate the help !

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df[['startTime', 'endTime']].head().to_dict('list'))` and check my previous comment about to convert columns.